# Adding css to multiple kendo grids on the same page

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
$grid.element.find('.k-grid-header .k-header').css('background-color', '#b9babb');
$grid.element.find('.k-grid-header .k-header').css('font-weight', 'bold');

// this works

```
onload = function () {
  $('.k-grid-header .k-header').css('background', '#b9babb');
  $('.k-grid-header .k-header').css('font-weight', 'bold');
};
```

Comment: What is the issue? That code you try is working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Do what you are doing but do not narrow it to one simple grid. I.e. do:

```
$('.k-grid-header .k-header').css('background-color', '#b9babb');
$('.k-grid-header .k-header').css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/KKsk3/ (click on the button to re-style the header of both grids).

Comment: Thanks called the function from the onload instead of a button.